# wget not downloading HTML

Tags: web-crawler, wget

I wanted to download the plain html content of this site: https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/02/20/what-technology-stack-does-airbnb-use/#c69fd2a4025c

I tried some options, such as `wget -E -H -k -p`.

I noticed, that the last part of the URL is changing, whenever I enter this page again. `#c69fd2a4025c` then becomes `#60dd96344025` for example. Is that the reason, why the download (which worked many times before) is not working this time?

I always get an index.html file, which doesn't give me any content.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment ID after the `#` character is not transmitted to the server at all.  Javascript on the page has access to it, so it is probably used for some sort of link tracking or metrics.

I'm in Europe, so the site does not serve me any content under that URL, only a doorway page with a consent form.  You may be able to work around such issues by adding cookies, but I suspect that you will then run into anti-ad-blocker restrictions.

In general, it is only possible to capture content from web sites with tools like [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).  In some cases, even browser automation may be needed before you can access content.